# How to combine requests from different threads into a batch request to another rpc interface, and then return the results to different threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, multiprocessing, c++14

The RPC idl is as follows which allows a list of input. I simplified the logic in rpc, assuming it returns the square of the input.

```
Req{
  list<int> input
}

Rsp{
  list<int> output
}
 
Req.input = {1, 2, 3} -> Rsp.output = {1, 4, 9}
Req.input = {2} -> Rsp.output = {4}
Req.input = {4} -> Rsp.output = {16}
```

```
Thread 1: req.input = {1}
Thread 2: req.input = {2}
Thread 3: req.input = {3, 4}
```

There are three threads in total, need to call rpc 3 times. I want to combine the requests of the three threads and only request rpc one time.
The request after combined is req.input = {1, 2, 3, 4}. The response is rsp.output{1, 4, 9, 16}. Then ,return the result to each theads. For examle, thread 1 gets 1, thread2 gets 4, thread 3 gets {9, 16}.

My idea is to start another thread, combine the requests of the three threads and then call the rpc, and the three threads sleep and wait for the result to return. but i don't know how to return the result to the threee threads

Please provide ideas and sample code in C++.

Comment: Is the server prepared to handle _"aggregated requests"_ somehow??

Comment: _"Please provide ideas and sample code in C++."_ That's not a very good format for an SO question. It's going to be too broad, and attracting opinion based answers. Also requests for _"sample code"_ are more or less _off-topic_, in case you have nothing at hand to fix it.

Comment: Yes. The server can compute each one in the input list and put the result in output list.

Comment: The probably best idea is to [edit] your question, and add some details about the specific protocol used.

Answer (score 4):

One idea could be to make the thread wait for a certain condition using a `std::condition_variable`.

I've put it in an `event` class together with a `std::mutex` and a `bool` to signal that the condition is fulfilled:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

struct event {
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool trig{false};

    void wait() {
        std::unique_lock lock(mtx);
        while (not trig) cv.wait(lock);
        trig = false;
    }

    void set() {
        std::lock_guard lock(mtx);
        trig = true;
        cv.notify_one();
    }
};
```

You can then provide such an `event` to the thread when starting the thread:

```cpp
struct thread_info {
    std::jthread th;
    event ev;        // the event to wait for
    int data;        // the data to be used by this thread
};

void bg(thread_info& ti) { // reference to the thread_info
    ti.ev.wait();          // wait for the event to get signalled
    // use ti.data here:
    std::cout << ti.data << std::endl;
}
```

A toy example to use the above:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::array<thread_info, 3> tis;

    {
        for (auto& ti : tis) {
            ti.th = std::jthread(bg, std::ref(ti));
        }
    }

    // call rpc here
    std::list<int> output{1, 4, 6};

    {
        auto it = output.begin();
        for (auto& ti : tis) {
            if(it == output.end()) break;
            ti.data = std::move(*it); // moving just to show intent
            ti.ev.set();              // set the event to signal data ready
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
4
1
6
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ovrTjTW1j)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it's fantastic! Could you show how to call the rpc? It needs to combine the request in each threads first

Comment: @mullerjohn You're welcome. You could just do the same thing as when distributing the data to the threads, but instead let the threads signal the main thread that their data is ready. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/TdhfKMvhW)